# Prove $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ if differentiable is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Below I have written a proof for the problem in my title and was wondering if the proof works

$$0=\lim_{h\to 0}|f(a+h)-f(a)-\triangledown f\cdot h|$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}|f(a+h)-f(a)-\big(f_xh_1+\cdots f_nh_n\big)|$$

and since $h \to 0$ implies $(h_1,\cdots ,h_n) \Longrightarrow (0,\cdots , 0)$

$$\big(f_xh_1+\cdots f_nh_n\big) =0 \text{ as } h\to 0$$

So we get continuity since

$$0=\lim_{h\to 0}|f(a+h)-f(a)|$$

Comment: In one dimension suppose $f(a^+)\ne f(a^-)$, but $ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a^++h)-f(a^+)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a^-)-f(a^--h)}{h}$.  Does this define the derivative at $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof from the book (also one in English :)).

\begin{align*} \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) &\iff \lim_{x \to x_0} |f(x)- f(x_0)| = 0 \\ \\ &\iff \lim_{x \to x_0} \left|f(x)- f(x_0)\right| \frac{\|x-x_0\|}{\|x-x_0\|}= 0 \\ \\ & \iff \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}\|x-x_0\| = 0 \\ \\ & \iff \lim_{x \to x_0} \left(\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}\right)\|x-x_0\| = 0 \\ \\  & \leq \lim_{x \to x_0} \left(\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| + |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}\right)\|x-x_0\| \\ \\ & = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|} \|x-x_0\| + |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|   \end{align*}

By the differentiability assumption we have,

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}  = 0$$

Hence, each limit exists separately i.e;

\begin{align*} &\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|} \|x-x_0\| + |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| \\ \\ & =\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|} \|x-x_0\| + \lim_{x \to x_0} |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| \\ \\ & = 0  \end{align*}

Therefore,

$$ \lim_{x \to x_0} |f(x)-f(x_0)| = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$

Comment: This is clear.  Thanks.  and just wondering, were there any problems with my proof?

Comment: Yes, when you write that second equality with the limit, the quantities on each side of the minus sign don't go to zero with different orders and so you can just call $\nabla f(a) \cdot h$ zero in the limit and keep the other term i.e $f(a+h) - f(a)$

Comment: What do you mean by "go to zero with different orders".  I assume you mean that if I had $|2h|-|h|$ then these terms approach $0$ at different rates where $2h$ will equal $0$ faster?  But more importantly, is what your hinting at a rule that states that I can't get rid of one term based on that reason if it applies to more terms in the expression?

Comment: Yes and yes. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Probar que si $f:\mathbb{R^{n}}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R^{n}}$ es diferenciable en $a\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$, entonces es continua en $a$.

Supongamos que $f$ es diferenciable en $a\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$, es decir, existe una única transformación lineal $\lambda:\mathbb{R^{n}}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^{n}}$ tal que 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{h\longrightarrow 0} \frac{\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda (h)\vert}{\vert h\vert}=0.
$$
Observe que 
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & \leq & \vert f(a+h)-f(a)\vert & = & \left \vert \lambda(h)+\vert h\vert \cdot \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda (h)}{\vert h\vert}\right\vert \\ 
 &  &  & \leq & \vert\lambda (h)\vert +\vert h\vert\cdot\dfrac{\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda (h)\vert}{\vert h\vert} \\ 
 &  &  & \leq & M\cdot\vert h\vert +\vert h\vert\cdot\dfrac{\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda (h)\vert}{\vert h\vert}
\end{array} 
$$
Así, 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{h\longrightarrow 0} 0\leq\displaystyle\lim_{h\longrightarrow 0} \vert f(a+h)-f(a)\vert\leq\displaystyle\lim_{h\longrightarrow 0} \vert h\vert\left(\vert\lambda\vert+\dfrac{\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda (h)\vert}{\vert h\vert}\right)
$$

$
\begin{array}{rl}
\Rightarrow & \displaystyle\lim_{h\longrightarrow 0} \vert f(a+h)-f(a)\vert=0 \\
             & x=a+h \qquad h\longrightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow x\longrightarrow a \\
\Rightarrow  & \displaystyle\lim_{x\longrightarrow a} \vert f(x)-f(a)\vert=0 \\
\Rightarrow  & \displaystyle\lim_{x\longrightarrow a} f(x)=f(a) \\
\Rightarrow  & f \mbox { es continua en } a
\end{array}
$

Comment: I know you speak spanish, but he's asking in english hahaha